# How to select childs based on their position in the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

say I have html like this

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='dad'>
        <div class='teen'>
            <div class='baby'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='dad'>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I target the divs based on how far they are from the parent? e.g. `.baby` has 3 parents ahead of it, and `.teen` has 2 parents ahead of it. Any way to do this? Because what I eventually wanna do is target every 2nd child(). So in this instance i'd like to select `.dad` and `.baby`. But I don't want to select a fixed amount, I want it to infinitely select every 2nd child() in the DOM tree.

Comment: If you start at the lowest level you can just go `$('.baby').parent().parent()` to skip over the immediate parent.

Comment: Yeah but as I said `.baby` position isn't known as there can be infinite childs. Preferably would like to start at `.parent` and then iterate from there downwards

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: What about that div with no class shouldn't it be selected?

Comment: Yes, an answer in jQuery will be preferable.

Comment: its still unclear. What if there are two `.baby` nodes under same parent? What do you mean by 2nd child? is it deep 2nd child or should it even count in first level of nodes?

Comment: Maybe with jQuery's [:even](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector?

Comment: 'What if there are two .baby nodes under same parent?' - then they would be treated as the same (both selected under the same circumstances). I said 2nd child which isn't exactly the right terminology, but by 2nd child I mean it has 2 parents. 3rd child would have 3 parents etc

Comment: @Zorgan, But in that case `baby` has three parents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var $result = $("div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).parents("div").length % 2 != 0; // if the number of div parents is not a pair number
});

$result.each(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** If you want to include all parents then use this:

```
return $(this).parents().length % 2 != 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is using jquery :odd selector.

$("div:odd").css("background-color", "yellow"); 
$("div:even").css("background-color", "green");

Here the alternate div's are colored differently.

Comment: Thanks this is better. Actually it doesn't work as it gets every 2nd div not every 2nd in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think `nth child selector` should do the trick.

Relevant [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_nthchild.asp)

Example:

```
$("p:nth-child(3)")
```

The above code snippet would select each `<p> element` that is the third child of its parent. You can get fancy with the selectors and values. Further [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) on CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nthLevelChield(n){
    var targetedNode=$('.parent');
    for(var i=0; i<n ; i++){
         targetedNode=targetedNode.children().eq(0);
       }
    return targetedNode;
}
```

Where **n** is child level variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this for single div-

```
 $('.dad').children().children().eq(0);
```

and if you have more than one div and u need for all you can try this-

```
$('div').each(function(){
$(this).children().children().eq(0);
})
```